# TinyMce plugin, how to copy 'Link' functionality

Tags: tinymce

I'm creating a new plugin for TinyMce. However I cannot find any examples to see some of the functionality I've seen in other plugins. I've read their source code but I cannot find where it is done:

When you click on an 'A' element, the link/unlink buttons in the taskbar become enabled.
When you right click on an 'A' element, then click on the "Insert/edit link" icon that is shown in the popup menu, the "Insert/edit link" window is setup (has all the attributes for that particular link) prefilled.
Could you suggest somewhere where I could learn how to do this? A file and line number is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a part of what you want. To highlight a UI button (link) you may do

```
tinymce.get(editorid).contentManager.setActive('link', true);
```

**EDIT:**  For the other functionality have a look at `editor_plugin_src.js/editor_plugin.js` in the directory `tiny_mce\plugins\advlink\`. It is only small in size. You will find that a file called `link.htm` is being called to form the popup. Hope this helps.